# MongoDB - Can I have multiple sort fields in a map reduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a map/reduce that I noticed was taking nearly 10 seconds to run, even though no results were being returned.  Using the mongo shell, I was able to determine that my initial query was the culprit.  I was able to add a 2nd sort field to the query, which sped it up drastically.

However, when I try to add that 2nd sort field to my map reduce, I get the error "could not create cursor over [collection] for query ...".  Is there any way for me to add a 2nd sort field to the map reduce?

Edit: The goal of my query is to find the first record created by each user/day.  So the key that I am emitting is the user's id + created on day, ignoring any time.  That way I am grouping all records created by a user on a given day.  In my reduce, I am then taking the record that was created first.  I have actually ditched using map/reduce and am now doing essentially the same thing, but with a normal find() and then some javascript to group and reduce.

Comment: Can you show the queries and map reduce you were trying to use?

Comment: Map reduce does not support sorting of input, only output

Comment: Also, please explain what you are trying to do query wise. Provide input, output and same documents. It's likely you'll be much better off with using the aggregation framework.

Comment: Sammaye, mongodb's map reduce only supports sorting of input, not output, as documented here:  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce

Comment: Odd they must have just added that input feature however you can sort output of documents simply by querying the output collection and sortign the documents